# Verify that my Regex works as expected

Tags: c#, regex

It's my first regex for production code, until now I've always avoided to write them myself and now I'm a bit worried if it really works as it is expected to. I made a lot of attempts trying to break it, but I really don't want to rely on this, especially when I have zero experience.

My regex should match exactly this pattern

- first character must be one of the letters (not case sensitive) - `K,C,M,X,S,W`
- second character must be a digit from `0-9`
- a hyphen `-`
- 4 alphanumeric characters (`A-Z` or `0-9`) (not case sensitive) and
- one letter (`A-Z`) (not case sensitive).

And that's it. It can't be shorter, it can't be longer, it must match exactly this pattern. What I have for now is this:

```
string RegExPattern = @"^(K|C|M|X|S|W){1}[0-9]{1}[-]{1}[A-Z0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}$";
if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtCode.Text, RegExPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Fail");
    return false;
}
```

Is there any tool, or some other way to verify the behavior of a regex and is this regex correct for the matching pattern I explained above?

Comment: The `{1}` is redundant because a single match is implied.

Comment: You can also simplify `(K|C|M|X|S|W)` to `[KCMXSW]`, and you don't need `-` in a character set (use just `-` instead).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice tool to verify and develop regular expressions: http://www.debuggex.com. Nevertheless I'd advise you to concrete your regular expressions with the bunch of unit tests.

Comment: This is good for ad hoc testing, but isn't a perfect all around tool. I recommend removing the word "perfect" from the answer.  Regular expressions can be tested automatically, and automatic tests are usually preferred over manual tests because you can run them faster and more often.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley yes, you're right. I'm a big fan of unit-testing and there is no tool to replace them. My answer is this only because author was asking about a tool.

Comment: Unfortunately: "This is a beta version. It supports a subset of JavaScript regexes." ...and the JavaScript flavor supports only a subset of .NET regexes.  You'll probably find [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) more useful.

Comment: @Alan Moore, yep but it grows fast and even now it's already quite good. I can also suggest using http://www.regexper.com/ and http://gskinner.com/RegExr/. These tools I also used but a lot less then the first one.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that is correct.

However, all the `{1}` are redundant, you can make a set of the first character insted of using the `|` operator, and you don't need a set for the dash:

```
string RegExPattern = @"^[KCMXSW][0-9]-[A-Z0-9]{4}[A-Z]$";
```

There are tools for writing and testing regular expressions, but you can only use them to test any variations in the input that you can think of, and it seems that you have already done that.

Comment: Not answering the question at all.

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy: What do you mean?

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy: part of the question includes the phrase "is this regex correct for the matching pattern I explained above". This answer addresses that part.

Comment: Yeah fair enough, but the title of the question is "how to be sure that it works exactly as it's expected".

Comment: Thanks, what I was looking for also was some kind of improvement cause I knew I didn't write the regex the best possible way.

Answer (score 2):

The best tool is a suite of unit tests, or a single test that iterates over several dozen chunks of text.

Create a text file that has a whole bunch of lines of text that are similar to the data this pattern will be used against. Make sure that some lines match, and some lines that won't match different parts of the rule (eg: a pattern that matches everything but the first character, one that matches everything but the last character, one with only 2 or 3 characters rather than four, etc.

Then, write a small program that reads each line of text and runs your expression against it. Have it print the line numbers of the lines that match, and then compare that list of numbers against your expected results.